# Why is an INSERT query hanging indefinitely and locking up PostgreSQL database and pgAdmin

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I have a Spring Batch application (though I THINK I've eliminated Spring as the culprit -- more below) that uses the `42.2.8` release of the `org.postgresql` driver to connect to a PostgreSQL 11.1 database, provided as an AWS RDS instance. The app is being migrated over from an Oracle setup, but whenever I try to run the application to ingest data, it locks up the process indefinitely and, to an extent, seems to lock up the database itself...

For some reason, the code that works fine for ingesting into Oracle, when changed over to instead target postgres, seems to completely choke on INSERT statements (whether Spring generates them or whether I try to bypass all calls to Spring by putting the INSERT statement and connection info hard-coded into the top of the application main function).

On top of that, there are certain things I can't even do in pgAdmin until I kill the hung process. The web interface also hangs indefinitely, and I'm trying to figure out a rhyme or reason for it (I can't blame the table, because other tables can get blocked and can sometimes be accessed; sometimes I can make new connections, sometimes I can't; I do seem to reliably be able to refresh tables that I've previously queried, so long as I don't kill the tab/connection)

I'm not sure if Spring is autowiring something or injecting something auto-magically around the simple call, so I'm going to make a simple Java app to try to eliminate that possibility... I might also try a different postgres driver, but it concerns me that it seems to hang the pgAdmin web interface... but anyway I'm hoping someone has encountered and either fixed or mitigated this situation before, and it just didn't end up in an easily-Googleable article yet

Anyone have this issue? With or without Spring Batch?

Comment: What's the state of that session when you check `pg_stat_activity`. The only situation where an INSERT could "lock" is, if there is another un-committed transaction that inserted the same primary key value. If you can't refresh tables you have changed, that seems a strong indication that your application is missing a commit when it does the changes

Comment: I cannot seem to establish any connection to view that table or make that query myself, but I did ask someone else who has an active connection to query that table and the state is "active", with wait_event = "relation", wait_event_type="lock"

Comment: Then some other session (transaction) has uncommitted changes - as that is an INSERT, it's highly likely that transaction is inserting the same values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name concurrent insert of conflicting keys would lead to a blocked transactionid lock, not a blocked on relation lock.  A relation lock suggest the other session is doing a vacuum full, create index, something like that, or an explicit table lock.

Comment: okie - pretty sure I figured it out - not sure how much you guys helped out, but I did determine there was another process marked as blocking and that led me to another connection that was being held open, and which I'm guessing was blocking the table in question due to an uncommitted truncation, which apparently Oracle didn't mind, or else auto committed (?)... but regardless postgres got blocked by. I restructured the code to close that connection and it seems to not be blocking things anymore. I appreciate your patience!

Comment: Did that code maybe run a DDL statement that wasn't committed? (In Postgres DDL is transactional just like DML)

Comment: the function call is simply passed the function name and any arguments via the python `psycopg2` module's `connection.cursor.callproc()` method - in the `pg_stat_activity` table, the record had a "select from (function_name)" type of syntax - not sure if that helps answer your question (?)

Answer (score 0):

First, I found the Sessions tab on the pgAdmin Dashboard, which pointed me to another session that was marked as blocking the new one - a truncation function, called from a python script, that completed and returned control (and all the data was gone from the table) - so it wasn't obvious it was still blocking anything

I found [this table/matrix of locking/blocking relationships](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/02/15/when-postgresql-blocks/) which does clearly show that truncation will block everything:

[image: Table locks block reads &/or writes during DDL]

Anyway... I realized that the python script was trying to reuse the database connection from Step 1 (direct call from python via psycopg2 to a stored procedure in Oracle, or function in PostgreSQL), then holding onto the db connection  (all steps were in the scope of a single with statement block) as it started a java process for Step 2 (which would write to the tables that were truncated in Step 1). The python process would wait until the java process terminated, then pass the same db connection to the stored procedure called directly from python in Step 3.

Criticisms of this approach granted, Oracle seems to have handled this just fine, but Postgres disagreed, locking up on Step 2 because I can only assume from my reading and the few records I could find, the truncation was not actually committed or something (?)

My resolution seems to have come from closing the connection in python, after Step 1 was complete, before starting the Java process. I then get another connection for Step 3 and it seems everything works now

Comment: This is because TRUNCATE in Oracle is DDL which automatically commits, whereas TRUNCATE in Postgres is transactional and needs a COMMIT - if you forget the commit, the table is locked, because TRUNCATE request an exclusive table lock.

Comment: OK, so IF I wanted to keep the connection open for reuse, I would need to put the `TRUNCATE` inside a `BEGIN .. COMMIT; END;` block? because that's throwing an error :-/ -- [the TRUNCATE docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-truncate.html) seem to indicate I should commit the "surrounding transaction" somehow:  -- BUT [the transaction isolation docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html) suggest a syntax that throws various errors...??? Is my only option to close the connection? Or what?

Comment: Depends on how you configured your JDBC connection. If you turned off autocommit (which is highly likely) then it's enough to run `commit` after the truncate (or call `Connection.commit();`)

Comment: So, the lack of a commit that was causing a problem was the truncation function call, which was made through python, not JDBC. I THINK that autocommit is active through that python driver/connection, because when I close the connection, the block is released and I can continue on and do the inserts through the Java driver. ---- What I am trying to determine is how to commit the truncation on a more granular level (inside the stored procedure/function) but I don't see anywhere that tells me how to `COMMIT` a `TRUNCATE` (?)

Comment: I don't use Pyhton, but you could simply run `commit` after you ran `truncate`

Comment: Ok - I can't quite figure out HOW to "run a commit" after a truncate. I haven't found documentation and simply adding `commit;` after the `truncate {table};` statement, while being one of the only ways I don't get an error for the `CREATE` statement, nonetheless gives a `PL/pgSQL function truncate_function() line ## at COMMIT` error when I actually run the function

Comment: As for python, I believe I am able to close the connection and that automatically commits the actions of the function(i.e. truncation), but I am looking for a way to ensure that the SQL function will actually commit the truncation by itself, and thus will not rely upon python or any other calling language/framework to close its connection. Can you suggest a function syntax that will do this? I've tried about 10 different ways, several of which were suggested by the DBA that is more familiar with Oracle, and none have both compiled and properly executed without error.

Comment: You can't `commit` inside a function in Postgres